# Kobold Outrider adaptation option

Tags: dnd-3.5e, prestige-class

[This](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?348310-Build-Kobold-mounting-Dire-Weasel-(ranger-)) thread on the Giant in the Playground forums presents a kobold mounted ranger build. The author uses the halfling outrider prestige class (from *Complete Warrior*) adapted for kobolds, stating that

> it actually says in the halfling outrider description, under
>   adaptation, that it can be used to exemplify any racial mounted class
>   such as lizard riding elves, worg riding goblins, etc, etc.

[The fourth post](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showsinglepost.php?p=17460915&postcount=4) contains a breakdown of 15 levels of the build. The author mixes both the prestige classes wild plains outrider and kobold (that is, halfling) outrider and explicitly states that the latter is a halfling outrider adaptation and not a wild plains outrider adaptation.

But I can't find an adaptation section for halfling outrider in *Complete Warrior*.

**Is there an official adaptation of the halfling outrider prestige class?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *Complete Warrior* prestige class **halfling outrider** doesn't have an Adaptation entry, nor did it in its original appearance in *Sword and Fist*. The [Giant in the Playground forum posts](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?348310-Build-Kobold-mounting-Dire-Weasel-(ranger-)) claiming the halfling outrider *does* have an adaptation entry is likely a result of confusion with the similarly named and themed *Complete Adventurer* prestige class **wild plains outrider**, which has the Adaptation entry the author describes.